# Relating $E[X]$ and $E[h(X)]$ by 'adjusting' the PDF

Tags: distributions, self-study, expected-value, density-function

I have just started studying statistics and I have been introduced to PDFs and expected values. Now the formal definition of $E[X]$ for a continuous random variable is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}tf(t)\mathrm dt$ where $f(x)$ is the PDF. Also this extends to formulating $E[X^2]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}t^2f(t)\mathrm dt$. Now as far I can see there are two ways to find $E[X^n]$ in general, one is to just plug in $t^n$ in place of $t$ in the integrand, and another possible way is to somehow adjust the PDF, so that it corresponds to $E[Y]$ for some other random variable.

Let me take a case of the standard uniform density function $f(t)=1$. $E[X]$ for this is simply $1/2$ and $E[X^n]$ in general is $1/(n+1)$. Let's say I was to go about this by considering some other probability density function that gives me the same expected value, how would one go about making a choice for the adjustments to be made in the PDF?

---

**My Attempt**:

Since I want to transform the problem into something of the form $E[Y]$. I would need a linear PDF with area bounded being $1$ from $x\in[0,1]$. So that function would be $g(t)=2t$, but now if I use the definition of $E[Y]=\int_{0}^{1}tg(t)\mathrm dt$, I get $E[Y]=2/3$ while I am supposed to get $1/3$.

---

What corrections have to be made. Also would the limits of the random variable change during such a transformation of the PDF. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how 'adjusting' the pdf helps in the calculation. One way of finding $E[h(X)]$ is by evaluating $\int h(t)f(t)\,dt$, as you say. Another way is to find the distribution of $h(X)$ and then take its expectation.

Comment: i don't think "adjusting the pdf" is a valid approach. by definition, $E[h(X)] = \int h(t) f(t)\:dt$. you can perform a change of variables in the integral if you like, but that's the definition.

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but you might find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician i remember being confused when first learning this stuff by why we sometimes do $E(h(X))$ by $\int x f_h(x)\,\text dx$ where $f_h$ is the pdf of $h(X)$ vs doing $\int h(x)f(x)\,\text dx$. LOTUS shows these are the same so the answer is just to do the easier one

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about [*change of measure* theorems for martingales?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem)